# How to select a dropdown option with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make this work for an hour, it's getting ridiculous. Would someone please show me how to select a drop down option with jquery?

HTML

```
 <select class="my_select_box" name="accepted_orders_customer_number"
 data-placeholder="Choose a Customer Number" style="display: none;">
     <option></option>
     <option value="1">1: go co.2 company</option>
     <option value="2">2: jack brian, banana company</option>
     <option value="3">3: jack marley</option>
     <option value="4">4: jack daniels</option>
     <option value="5">5: mary brian</option>
     <option value="6">6: Cloud Strife</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('[name=accepted_orders_customer_number] option').filter(function () {
        return ($(this).val() == 2); //To select jack brian
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyzx3/), and I am using the jquery ui for the dropdowns

EDIT:

I need to select it by the value. I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that right away. I can't select by its index since those won't be as meaningful as the values of the options.

Comment: Check my answer it is shortest and will work for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your fiddle as well as removing `style="display: none;"` for the `select` in your HTML markup and it should works as expected.

However you can shorten your code by using:

```
$('select.my_select_box option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyzx3/4/)**

---

It's probably happen a conflict here, try to use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[name=accepted_orders_customer_number] option').filter(function () {
        return ($(this).val() == 2); //To select jack brian
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: This works in fiddle but not on my computer? The console is registering no errors and my jquery is 1.11.0. I find it strange.

Comment: Are you using Wordpress or any other libraries than conflict with jQuery?

Comment: I'm not using wordpress, only jquery, jquery ui, jquery cookies, and tcpdf. None of them seem to conflict. I tried your code but no luck, I  tried modifying it a bit too by adding double quotation marks around the name but it still didnt work.

Comment: Yup, you're right. There is a "conflict", apparently. It exists because of the jquery ui, which I need to look into to debug this. When I removed it, your code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

```
$('select.my_select_box').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as this

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/CWvwn/2564/)

JQuery:

```
$('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
```

Markup:

```
<select>
  <option>1: go co.2 company</option>
  <option>2: jack brian, banana company</option>
  <option>3: jack marley</option>
  <option>4: jack daniels</option>
  <option>5: mary brian</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need to select the option by the value. Sorry, should have said something earlier. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('[name=accepted_orders_customer_number]').val('2');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qyzx3/7/

Of course, I removed your `style` attribute on your `select` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it locally but it doesn't run also. I don't know if this is a conflict that's there for my jquery ui library.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better selector for that:

```
 $('select.my_select_box > option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
```

[Link to working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyzx3/4/)

Comment: It doesnt work on fiddle. Also, I forgot to remove the display:none style on the HTML code, in case you'd get confused. The jquery ui adds it in automatically.

Comment: @markovchain No worries about display: none, I got it.  I edited in a working fiddle.

Comment: Ah, you're right. But I need to select by the value, sorry, I should have said it earlier. I edited the question

Comment: @markovchain Done, with a tested Fiddle!  CSS selectors are really neat.

Comment: This works on fiddle well, but it's not on my computer. I don't know what's wrong since there isn't an error showing up

Comment: In that case, I can't help you further.  Please upvote/accept my answer and post a new question when you get farther in your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You just need [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/qrGg9/)

```
$(function () {
    $('select.my_select_box').val(2);
});
```

---

Read [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)